# Is it possible to rename an Azure App Service plan using the Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, rename

Is it possible to rename an **App Service Plan**?

I have already tried in both the old and new portals and can't find any rename options.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

No, you can't.

However, if you create a new App Service Plan in the same region and resource group then you can move all your sites to the new App Service Plan and delete the old one.

Comment: Is it possible to change the resource group of a Web Site?

Comment: Yes, using powershell. This page has more details: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-move-resources/

Comment: It is also possible by using the Azure Portal. In the Web App settings you can choose "Change App Service Plan".

Comment: You may need to scale up your existing app service plan first for this option to work. It didn't work on the shared tier.

Comment: Not necessarily. You can't move all your sites to the new plan if the new plan happens to be created in a different workspace ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-plan-manage#move-an-app-to-another-app-service-plan))

Comment: "Change App Service Plan" doesn't "rename" an app service plan. It "moves" a web app to a different app service plan. Neither the source nor destination app service plan names are renamed.

Answer (score 10):

No but you can change it like this (if it is in the same region and resource group as mentioned by Zain Rizvi):

Create a new App Service Plan and bind it to the correct Subscription and Resource Group. Example:

[image]

Then go to your App Service and choose "Change App Service plan"

[image]

Comment: You may need to scale up your existing app service plan first for this option to work. It didn't work on the shared tier.

Comment: If you vote down please say why. Hard to improve answers otherwise